# Any string manipulation libraries for ChucK?

Tags: string, chuck

Can anyone point to string manipulation libraries for string in **ChucK**?
I can hardly find anything concerning strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official [ChucK documentation](http://chuck.cs.princeton.edu/doc/program/stdlib.html) is strangely missing some information.

There is another ChucK doc available from the Standford University.

[The link to this](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~spencer/ckdoc/). It seems more complete.

Especially it includes the [string stdlib](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~spencer/ckdoc/stdlib.html#string).